# [nodemailer][nodejs] cant send email from server

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I get the following error when using nodemailer on my server, it works locally (classic)

```
Error: Connection timeout
at SMTPConnection._formatError (/var/www/notion-to-self/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:784:19)
at SMTPConnection._onError (/var/www/notion-to-self/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:770:20)
at Timeout.<anonymous> (/var/www/notion-to-self/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:229:22)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7) {
code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
command: 'CONN'} unhandled
```

I do `nc -v -u smtp.ethereal.email 587` and the connection works `Connection to smtp.ethereal.email 587 port [udp/*] succeeded!` and if I contact the server from my terminal `nc -v -u ip.of.server  587` I also get a `succeded`

Here is my transporter

```
  const transporter = isProduction
    ? nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'Mailjet',
        auth: {
          user: 'xxx',
          pass: 'xxx'
        }
      })
    : nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: 'smtp.ethereal.email',
      port: 587,
      secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
      auth: {
        user: 'some.user@ethereal.email', // generated ethereal user
        pass: 'password' // generated ethereal password
      }
    })
```

I launch it with `NODE_ENV=development node name_of_script.mjs`

It works locally. I am logged in as root, everything executes fine until I come to the transporter. same version of node as on the local environment `v17.2.0`. How can I debug a SMTP connection... seems its open

Comment: Are you sure that the environment variable changes the value of `isProduction`? that part isn't in the post.

Comment: yes 100%. I `console.log` the value and its either true or false, depending whether I set it to production or development. It doesn't work with both.